# cannot pass django object to angular front end

Tags: python, django, angular

I am using Django 2.1.5 and Angular 7.3.1. I have a Django backend class DetailView that I am trying to use to pass an object to the Angular front end. I know the DetailView is working fine because I can see the object when I render a template with Django. For some reason I cannot seem to pass it to Angular via the Django API.

When I load the page nothing is displayed for `dogdetail` and the console has the error: `DogdetailComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]`

I have tried several variants and syntax, etc. I would think if the Django API is getting the object correctly, than Angular should be able to pick it up from the API endpoint.

I used Postman to access the API endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/dogdetail/` and I get the dog object and I can access its attributes.

My django **urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import DogList, DogDetailDjango, index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('dogs/', DogList.as_view(), name='doglist'),
    path('<int:pk>/dogdetail/', DogDetailDjango.as_view(), name='dogdetail'),
]
```

**dogdetail.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service'
import { Dog } from '../dog'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dogdetail',
  templateUrl: './dogdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dogdetail.component.scss']
})

export class DogdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  dogdetail : Dog[];

  constructor(private apiservice: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDog();
  }

    getDog(): void {
      this.apiservice.getDogDetail().subscribe(dogdetail=> this.dogdetail = dogdetail)
      console.log(this.dogdetail);
  }

}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http"
import { DogListComponent } from './dog-list/dog-list.component';
import { Dog } from './dog'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  apiURL: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  public getDogDetail(): Observable<Dog[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Dog[]>(`${this.apiURL}/1/dogdetail`);
}
}
```

**dogdetail view django:**

```
class DogDetailDjango(DetailView):
    model = Dog
    serializer_class = DogSerializer
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

**dogdetail.component.html**

```
dogdetail works!

    {{ dogdetail }}


    <h1>{{ dogdetail.name }} </h1>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like and what is the result of the HTTP query to get dog detail (can check this using the 'Network' tab of the developer console)?

Comment: Can you show `DogDetailDjango` code? We have no way to check if it's returning something wrong without it.

Comment: hello i added DogDetailDjango, the http query results in the error that i described above? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @ratrace123, the error you are seeing in the console is coming from the HTML and is because you are trying to access a property on an element that isn't defined yet. The most likely cause of this is that you are trying to read the object in the HTML before the asynchronous call to the back-end has been completed. it doesn't, at all, hint as to whether or not the API call is succeeding or what it may be returning. That's why I was asking to see both HTML, and the actual result of the API call according to the Browser.

Comment: @SimonK, I understand thanks for the explanation. I added the html for dogdetail

Comment: @ratrace123, change the line with the `h1` to be `<h1 *ngIf="dogdetail">{{ dogdetail.name }} </h1>`. This, at the least, will remove the error you are getting and you can then see if there is actually an issue with the API call.

Comment: @SimonK that was a great idea. I added that and it looks like the `dogdetail` object is not being passed. not sure if this error is relevant:`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/dogdetail' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:15713 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/dogdetail", ok: false, …}`

Comment: @ratrace123, the error is 100% relevant. It means that your server doesn't have CORS enabled which basically means that you cannot request a resource from a different Origin (which includes different ports!). What you need to do here is look-up enabling CORS with django (I have no relevant experience with django so cannot really help). This package looks like it might help: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: @SimonK i will look into that thanks so much for the help! I was suspicious of this...

Comment: @ratrace123  i think you need to use django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

@SimonK had the correct answer, I was only able to get rid of the errors after installing a CORS plug in for google chrome. I first tried creating the correct headers and everything and it would not work, only after i installed the plug in did i stop getting errors.